# Improving performance with a flat table and a backgroung sql job

Tags: sql-server, performance, caching

I'm running a classifieds website that has ads and comments on it. As the traffic has grown to a considerable amount and the number of ads in the system have reached over 1.5 million out of which nearly 250K are active ads.

Now the problem is that the system has been designed to be very dynamic in terms of the category of the ads and the properties each kind of ad can have based on it category or sub category, therefore to display an ad I have to join nearly 4 to 5 tables.

To solve this issue I have created a flat table (conceptually what I call a publishing table) and populate that table with an SQL Job every 3 to 4 minutes. Now for web requests I query that table to show ad listings or details.

I also have implemented a data cache of around 1 minute for each unique url combination for ad listings and for each ad detail.

I do the same thing for comments on ads (i.e. cache the comments and as the comments are hierarchical, I have used a flat table publishing model for them also, again populated with an SQL Job)

My questions are as follows:

1. Is the publishing model with a backgroung sql job a good design approach?
2. What approach would you take or people take for scenarios like this?
3. How does a website like facebook show comments realtime with millions of users, keeping sure that they do not lose any comments data by only keeping it in the cache and doing batch updates ?

Comment: Without actual code questions, this is off topic for SO - you may want to try [programmers.se] or [dba.se]

Answer (score 1):

Starting at the end:

> 3.How does a website like facebook show comments realtime with millions of users, keeping sure
>   that they do not lose any comments data by only keeping it in the cache and doing batch updates ?

Two things:

- Smarter programming than you. They can put a larget etam on solving this problem for months.
- Ignorance. They really dont care too muich about a cache being a little outdated. Noone will really realize.
- Hardware ;) More and more powerful servers than yours.

That said, your apoproach sounds sensible.